# How to perform an update using mssql node module and close the connection properly

Tags: node.js, sql-server

```
 const sql = require('mssql');

 var dbConfig = {
 server: "localhost",
 database: "veiculos",
 user: "guest2",
 password: "mypassword",
 port: 1433,
 debug: true,
 encrypt: true  
 };

    sql.connect(dbConfig);
    const request = new sql.Request()

  request.query('update producao.carros set gostar += 1 where  carroid = 37', (err, result) => {


      console.log(result)


  })
```

When I run this code I get

**"tedious deprecated The default value for `options.encrypt` will change from `false` to `true`. Please pass `false` explicitly if you want to retain current behaviour. node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:230:23"**

and the record is not updated.

When I try to run twice, I get this:

**if (globalConnection) throw new Error('Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.')**

**Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.**

and the record is not updated and an exception stops the server.

The last error is clear, but why my record is not updated?

Answer (score 0):

close the sql connection after updating
use sql.close()
this will close Global connection and make it available for second request